# why "data" attribute is not working in canvas element

Tags: css, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am playing with the `data*` attribute and canvas together, I came to know that the `data*` property is not working in canvas element but it works on other element like div.

I am trying to achieve that if some one put mouse over the canvas, the message **"from canvas"** from `data*` property should be display but it's not. When I tried same with div tag then there would be display the data **"from div"**.

**CSS**

```
canvas[data-uname]:hover:after, div[data-uname]:hover:after{
    content: attr(data-uname);
    position: absolute;
    left: 1;
    top : 3%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <canvas id="myCanvas" data-uname = "from canvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
 </canvas>


<div data-uname = "from div">
    Hover on me
</div>
```

I am curious about why `data*` property is not working in canvas tag, Is there I am doing something wrong or it's happening by default.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nzr3bvqm/)

Answer (score 1):

This does not depend on the `data-uname` attribute. You get the same result if you omit the `[data-uname]` part from the selectors.

The issue is that the `:after` pseudo-element does not work for a `canvas` element. More exactly, specifications do not require it to work and do not even define what that might mean, and in practice browsers just ignore selectors like `canvas:after` (i.e. treat them as matching no elements).